# How to optimize this MySql script?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to optimze this MySql script:

```
SELECT SUM(p.IMPORT_PEN)
FROM pendientes p
WHERE EXISTS( 
 SELECT 1 
 FROM clientes cli 
 WHERE p.CLIENT_COD = cli.CLIENT_COD 
 AND cli.FAMCLIVTA_COD IN("N/D")
);
```

It takes 3,953s.

Tried the follow:

```
SELECT SUM(p.IMPORT_PEN)
FROM pendientes p
LEFT JOIN clientes c ON c.CLIENT_COD = p.CLIENT_COD
WHERE c.FAMCLIVTA_COD IN("N/D");
```

It takes 2,609s.

```
SELECT SUM(p.IMPORT_PEN)
FROM pendientes p, clientes c
WHERE p.CLIENT_COD = c.CLIENT_COD
AND c.FAMCLIVTA_COD IN ("N/D");
```

It takes 2,578s.

There are 5866 rows in db.
Cannot modify:

```
c.FAMCLIVTA_COD IN ("N/D")
```

Because they may be many values.

Can it be optimized?

Comment: Can you add indexes?

Comment: let us see the EXPLAIN from your queries